# API to get vehicle registration detail - API Setu

Tags: api, rest, postman

I'm trying to fetch the vehicle registration detail through an API. I did a little bit of research and found out this website is providing API for this thing

https://apisetu.gov.in/api/transport#/APIs/rvcer

but unable to fetch it. There is no documentation available on it. Anyone knows how to use that API to fetch the vehicle registration detail